# Git Push failed when trying to deploy branch

Tags: git, ubuntu, vps, digital-ocean

I'm working on setting up my first VPS on DigitalOcean (and in general). Following this guide https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-automatic-deployment-with-git-with-a-vps. However, everytime I try to push my local branch to the VPS I receive the error

`Push failed: Failed with error: fatal: Could not read from remote repository.`

I also chown the /var/www/project and /var/repo/project.git folders to the user I log in/commit as. I can't tell if this is git issue or if I haven't properly set permissions up on the VPS. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, needed to add the port to my git ssh

`git remote add live ssh://user@mydomain.com:PORT/var/repo/site.git`